# Ubuntu 14.04 not PC specific

Tags: ubuntu, email

I have recently become unable to send email to smtp.outlook.com

The server is not found. smpt-mail.outlook.com is found but my password is rejected.

Other mail servers function normally.

Nothing has been changed in my system apart for Ubuntu updates. I can still connect with Windows and other (earlier) Linux boxes. Both Trusty boxes fail with the same error mesage. (I am experimenting with upgading the spare one to 16.04).

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: "The server is not found" - Sounds like a DNS configuration problem on that single PC.  "but my password is rejected." - If the server is not found, depending on which client your using, they could be using the same error message for multiple failures.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. The error mesage reporst a configuration error. this appears for two boxes, ubuntu 14.04 and now, 16.04.

Comment: Sorry, ranhound, I'm not uded to this and I have been too slow.

Comment: The emaill account I am unable to connect to is the one provided by BT, and uses the smtp.outlook.com server. I now find that it is only via a BT connection that I am unable to connect. Really surprising. The configuration works for other servers (free Cloud WiFi). Several boxes with same result, 14.04 and 16.04, now. Win 10 and earlier Ubuntu work ok. Time to contact BT, I think.

Comment: Hi Ramhound       I believe that I now have the answer to the connection problem. My diagnosis has been confused by happenstance connections that prove some of my statements about the problem to be false. I am now not sure if the WiFi service provider is relevant.

The password rejection was triggered by connection to a domain to which I had no legitimate access.

The solution to my connection problems lie in Thunderbird configuration.

At last I believe I have found the answer, its here...

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2270096

Comment: For my TB 45.5.1 the setting is at...

Edit>Preferences>Advanced>General>Config Editor

Click 'I'll be careful'

Type ipv6 into the search box.

Double click the entry that is found,

network.dns.disableIPv6 

setting it to true.

This cures the problem for all WiFi connections that I have tried. For the moment I hesitate to mark this thread as 'solved' as I have been mistaken before, but, so far, since making the change, everything works.